# Memory increases every time I resize the window

Tags: c, winapi, direct2d

I have created a simple Win32 Application and try to fill the Client Area with a Color. When the line "Clear RenderTarget" is included I see that the memory increases a few KB every time I resize the window.

My WindowProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            if (pRenderTarget != NULL)
            {
                RECT rc;
                GetClientRect(globalWindowHandle, &rc);

                D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right, rc.bottom);

                pRenderTarget->Resize(size);

                InvalidateRect(globalWindowHandle, NULL, FALSE);
            }
            return  0;
        }
        break;
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HRESULT dx = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pFactory);

            if (FAILED(dx))
            {
                MessageBox(globalWindowHandle, "Error creating D2D1Factory", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
                return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
        break;
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            int ret = HandleKeyboardInput(uMsg, wParam, lParam);

            if (ret == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        break;
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HRESULT hr = CreateGraphicsResources();

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {

                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

                pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

                // Clear RenderTarget
                pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::SkyBlue));

                hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();

                if (FAILED(hr) || hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
                {
                    pRenderTarget->Release();
                    pSolidBrush->Release();
                    pRenderTarget = NULL;
                    pSolidBrush = NULL;
                }

                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

                return 0;
            }

        }
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            int box = MessageBox(hwnd, "Would you like to close the editor ?", "Question", MB_OKCANCEL);
            if (box == IDOK)
            {
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

CreateGraphicsResources

```
HRESULT CreateGraphicsResources()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if (pRenderTarget == NULL)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(globalWindowHandle, &rc);

        D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right, rc.bottom);

        hr = pFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
            D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
            D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(globalWindowHandle, size),
            &pRenderTarget);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            const D2D1_COLOR_F color = D2D1::ColorF(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0);
            hr = pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(color, &pSolidBrush);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {

            }
        }


    }
    return hr;
}
```

Globals:

```
BOOL ctrlPressed = FALSE;
HWND globalWindowHandle;
ID2D1Factory *pFactory;
ID2D1SolidColorBrush *pSolidBrush;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *pRenderTarget;
```

Do I miss something to free up memory or what could be the reason? If I resize the window e.g. 5 sec the memory goes from 4KB up to 22KB.

My OS is Windows 10 x64

Comment: Code looks OK in general, but it will not compile, in particular `CreateGraphicsResources()` has no return. Thus I suspect there is something else in your code that may cause memory leak.

Comment: Yeah i changed that but still no luck.

Comment: What memory are you talking about? Where do you get 4KB and 22KB?

Comment: the memory of the ram goes up (TaskManager->Details->Memory(private working set). It starts with 3/4KB and when I resize it goes higher and higher... I stopped at 22KB

Comment: I get about 6000Kb for that memory. You might be reading it wrong. That number can go up and down by a lot, depending on what Windows decides. It's not useful information for debugging. You can keep track of GDI objects in Task manager, that's more useful -- There doesn't appear to be any problem with your code. In `WM_DESTROY` you should safely release the handles (the way it is done in MSDN example), although in this specific example it won't show as memory/resource leak because the program exists right away anyway.

Comment: As long as you `->Release` stuff, you should be fine. And you should use a ComPtr wrapper... just for safety.

Comment: Working set is under the control of the OS.  It is not a good proxy for finding problems like memory leaks.  The amount of memory your program needs is only one of many factors the OS uses to determine the working set size for your process.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your answers. I guess the issue solved. In fact the memory did not go up much more.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be solved. In fact the memory did not go up much more so it seems the OS assigns the other memory.